# Can't save nested attribute in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes

Rails newb here. In my app I'm trying to create a database of Games that each have multiple MameControls as nested attributes. The fields for entering MameControls show up in the New view but not in Edit, the results aren't rendered in Show, and if i validate_presence_of :mameControls it won't save the form, stating "Mame controls can't be blank." And in the rails console, Game.first(or last, or any other record).mame_controls returns only `[]`. So as far as I can tell the nested attribute is not being saved, even though i'm pretty sure i've set everything up similarly to what is shown in Railscast #196. Here is the Game class:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :mame_controls, :dependent => :destroy

  attr_accessible :name, :year, :company, :designer, :genre,
  :sb_info, :wiki_link, :arcade_history_link, :arcade_museum_link, 
  :caesar_link, :wildcard_link, :mame_controls

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :mame_controls, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true

  validates_presence_of :name, :year, :company, :genre, :sb_info, :mame_controls

end
```

mame_control.rb:

```
class MameControl < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game

  attr_accessible :name, :game_action
end
```

The form code to enter in or edit MameControls is this.

in _form.html.erb:

```
  <% f.fields_for :mame_controls do |builder| %>
    <%= render "control_fields", :f => builder %>
<% end %>
```

_control_fields.html.erb:

```
<div class="field">
 <p>
     <%= f.label :name, "Mame Control Name" %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %><br />
  <%= f.label :game_action, "Game Action" %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :game_action %>
 </p>
</div>
```

in games_controller.rb:

```
 def new
    @game = Game.new
    5.times do
       mame_control = @game.mame_controls.build
     end
  end

def create
    @game = Game.new(params[:game])
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, turns out the problem was a couple things wrong with my use of `reject_if` in `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. First of all I was checking for the wrong variable name (embarrassing,) and I misunderstood what the method was actually doing, or rather not doing - if a previously filled entry is rejected for being blank (as in that lambda), it won't delete or null the corresponding index value in the array. It just won't do anything to it. You have to explicitly set the nested attribute record to `_destroy` to destroy. I had read up on `accepts_nested_attributes_for` from a theoretical standpoint but I should've understood its options better.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `:mame_controls_attributes` to `attr_accessible` and then creating the record. Then, when you edit the record, the edit view should also show the fields for `mame_controls`.

Also, why should the controls be visible in show action ? (show is meant to display the data, not edit it)

Comment: Thanks but I'm afraid adding :mame_controls_attributes to attr_accessible isn't making any difference. And don't worry, the controls are not in the show action. What i meant is simply that the data is not displaying (as static info) there either. Sorry for not being clear about that, I've fixed the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing a similar problem.  I got the nested form to display correctly, but when I submitted the form it wrote the parent object info to the database, but not the child (nested) object.

The solution for me was adding the following code to my (as if I were using your example) create method in games_controller.rb

```
def create
  @game = Game.new(params[:game])
  if @game.save
    @game.mame_control = MameControl.new(params[:mame_control])
    ...
```

And please also note that my parent object had a has_one relationship with the child, not has_many.